# Powershell script to auto install of IIS 7 and above

Tags: windows, powershell, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am a complete newbie at powershell. What I need is a powershell script that can automate the process of installing IIS7 or above. I have certain configurations to be made to the role services. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the following blog useful , with certain changes from using help i was able to install IIS from power shell with custom role services.I have the code here and the link to the blog is:

http://www.ithassle.nl/2010/09/powershell-script-to-install-and-configure-iis7-5/#codesyntax_1

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Checking Execution Policy
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
#$Policy = "Unrestricted"
$Policy = "RemoteSigned"
If ((get-ExecutionPolicy) -ne $Policy) {
  Write-Host "Script Execution is disabled. Enabling it now"
  Set-ExecutionPolicy $Policy -Force
  Write-Host "Please Re-Run this script in a new powershell enviroment"
  Exit
}

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define the variables.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
$InetPubRoot = "D:\Inetpub"
$InetPubLog = "D:\Inetpub\Log"
$InetPubWWWRoot = "D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot"

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Loading Feature Installation Modules
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
Import-Module ServerManager 

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Installing IIS
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
Add-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Common-Http,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Net-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Request-Monitor,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Filtering,Web-Performance,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Mgmt-Compat,RSAT-Web-Server,WAS -IncludeAllSubFeature

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Loading IIS Modules
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
Import-Module WebAdministration

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Creating IIS Folder Structure
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
New-Item -Path $InetPubRoot -type directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-Item -Path $InetPubLog -type directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-Item -Path $InetPubWWWRoot -type directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copying old WWW Root data to new folder
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
$InetPubOldLocation = @(get-website)[0].physicalPath.ToString()
$InetPubOldLocation =  $InetPubOldLocation.Replace("%SystemDrive%",$env:SystemDrive)
Copy-Item -Path $InetPubOldLocation -Destination $InetPubRoot -Force -Recurse

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setting directory access
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
$Command = "icacls $InetPubWWWRoot /grant BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(RX) BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)"
cmd.exe /c $Command
$Command = "icacls $InetPubLog /grant ""NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"":(OI)(CI)(F)"
cmd.exe /c $Command

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setting IIS Variables
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
#Changing Log Location
$Command = "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites -siteDefaults.logfile.directory:$InetPubLog"
cmd.exe /c $Command
$Command = "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/log -centralBinaryLogFile.directory:$InetPubLog"
cmd.exe /c $Command
$Command = "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/log -centralW3CLogFile.directory:$InetPubLog"
cmd.exe /c $Command

#Changing the Default Website location
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -name physicalPath -value $InetPubWWWRoot

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Checking to prevent common errors
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
If (!(Test-Path "C:\inetpub\temp\apppools")) {
  New-Item -Path "C:\inetpub\temp\apppools" -type directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Deleting Old WWWRoot
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
Remove-Item $InetPubOldLocation -Recurse -Force

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Resetting IIS
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
$Command = "IISRESET"
Invoke-Expression -Command $Command
```

Comment: Note:  This will only work on Server 2008 R2.  Not R1 (the last 32 bit server OS and the one I'm on...)

Answer (score 8):

I can able to install IIS using powershell script by following below step:

1) Create batch File (Setup_IIS_win10.bat) with following script in it

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath="%ThisScriptsDirectory%SetupIISPowerShellScript_win10.ps1"
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

2) Create powershell script file (SetupIISPowerShellScript_win10.ps1) with following script in it

```
# This script installs IIS and the features required to run asp.net applications

# * Make sure you run this script from an Admin Prompt!
# * Make sure Powershell Execution Policy is bypassed to run these scripts:
# * YOU MAY HAVE TO RUN THIS COMMAND PRIOR TO RUNNING THIS SCRIPT!
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServer
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpErrors
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpRedirect
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpLogging
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-LoggingLibraries
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestMonitor
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpTracing
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Security
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestFiltering
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Performance
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerManagementTools
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Metabase
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-BasicAuthentication
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WindowsAuthentication
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-StaticContent
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-DefaultDocument
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationInit
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIExtensions
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIFilter
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpCompressionStatic
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASP
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CGI
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET35
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET47
#Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ServerSideIncludes
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-Services45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-Http-Activation45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-TCP-PortSharing45
# If running in the console, wait for input before closing.
if ($Host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost")
{ 
    Write-Host "Press any key to close..."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.FlushInputBuffer()   # Make sure buffered input doesn't "press a key" and skip the ReadKey().
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
}
```

3) Run the batch file(Setup_IIS_win10.bat) with Adminitrator privilege

Hope it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of calling pkgmgr with the correct packages:

```
$packages = "IIS-WebServerRole;" +
    "IIS-WebServer;" +
    "IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;" +
    "IIS-StaticContent;" +
    "IIS-DefaultDocument;" +
#       ... some other packages here 
    "IIS-ManagementConsole;" +
    "IIS-ManagementService;" +
    "IIS-LegacySnapIn;" +
    "IIS-FTPManagement;" + 
    "WAS-NetFxEnvironment;" +
    "WAS-ConfigurationAPI"

Start-Process "pkgmgr" "/iu:$packages"
```

Depending on your platform, and on IIS version, there are some subtle differences. You can find more information [here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/installing-iis-70.html), [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/29/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2/), and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/27/managing-server-features-with-powershell-cmdlets-on-windows-2008-server-r2-beta.aspx).

Comment: Not working in Windows 8.1. Pkgmgr is obsolete in this system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice script.  I would suggest one addition for future installs \ applications to use the modified `wwwpath` and that would be to modify the registry.
You could do this easily with adding this to the bottom of your script:

```
set-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\ -Name PathWWWRoot -Value $InetPubRoot
```

Anyway thanks for posting.